# how to redirect the user to page in different app

Tags: forms-authentication

i have two web projects authenticating the user using  configuration.
let say web1,web2 once the user logs into web1 there a link is provided to web2 .

When a user requests a particular page in web2 app, it is redirected to login page once validated i wants to redirect to requested page.

I'm using
              strRedirect = Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"];

```
            if (strRedirect == null)
            {
                strRedirect = "~/default.aspx";
                Response.Redirect(strRedirect);
            }
            else
            {

                Response.Redirect(strRedirect);
            }
```

but this gives only relative path. By using URI url=Request.url gives the full path so how can i redirect the user to this page....?????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made correction in my web.config then it is working fine